# jquery autocomplete examples using backend database?

Tags: php, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

are there any good working examples where you get an autocomplete on a text based input form? looking for one thats DB based so the list can be updated ect...

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

here is an example using JQuery + Jquery ui + auto complete + remote data source 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/multiple-remote.html